# Issue with Combining 2 Gifs in Gimp

Tags: gimp, animation, gif

So I am trying to combine 2 gifs in gimp but my issue is that when editing and exporting both gifs separately they are fine, but when I try to be put them together and exported as 1 then It has issues like the 2nd gif loses it's original colors and there's green dots everywhere and the color distorts.

Gif 1

[image]

Gif 1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7Zzl.jpg

Gif 2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKUr2.jpg

Issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3AG8.jpg

Comment: I could not edit the second and third gif, because you uploaded them as MP4 files, not as GIF.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that each of the original elements had its own palette. 
On the combined GIF, the second clip is using the palette of the first one.

One option is to convert the files to 24 bits and reconvert it down to an indexed palette, taking now into account all the colors of the sequence. You will have fewer colors because some of the colors will not be used on one part of the animation and some other will. But that is the nature of the GIF format.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is caused because all GIFs use Indexed colour. It has nothing to do with GIMP really. The problem is with the image format itself, and the way that colours are stored in it. Anyway it's easy enough to fix.

Try this:

1. Open the first GIF image
2. Do *Image > Mode > RGB* - this will solve the colour problems when importing the GIF in the next step
3. Click and drag the second GIF onto the image

Export the finished GIF as you would normally

Answer (score 1):

A GIF image is color-indexed, each color is a one-byte index in a 256-colors (max) "color map".

When you edit such a file in Gimp, Gimp keeps it as color-indexed, and will coerce any color you use into the closest one in the color map (Gimp will not alter the color map on its own). This also applies to images you import in the project (`File>Open as layers...`, cut/paste, drag & drop from other images in Gimp.

To avoid the problem, you can concert the initial image to full RGB mode (`Image>Mode>RGB`). You then have the full color space available for editing.

However:

- If you export to GIF again, the image will be color-indexed again so all the colors used will have to be shoe-horned into the 256 color map. Image degradation will likely ensue.
- A somewhat more recent variant of the GIF format allows one color-map **per frame** (while GIMP only supports the older one-map-per-animation), so even trivial editing of one image with Gimp can degrade it.
- The WebP format is supported by all modern browsers and removes most GIF restrictions.